# Great internet speed but several services almost unusable

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I've had some issues with my PC for the last few months, and not sure what else to do.

Some information:

- I have 1GB download speed
- PC has 96GB ram, Intel i9 9900k, GeForce RTX 2070 super
- I have problems with YouTube (hangs while buffering every 10 seconds, even on the lowest video quality)
- I am constantly disconnecting/reconnecting to Google Docs and Sheets. I'll write something and it will disappear and refresh the connection. This happens literally every 10 seconds
- Download speeds are horrific. Takes ages to download relatively small files
- I can stream twitch just fine, and all video games work seamlessly
- This happens on both ethernet and my WiFi adapter
- Happens in all web browsers
- Happens on all accounts on my PC (even a freshly created one)
- All other devices in the house are completely fine
- No VPNs running
- Windows defender off, no other firewalls
- I'm a software engineer, and I run react-native servers. But even when I restart my computer and make sure all node processes are killed, problem persists
- The only things I've done in my BIOS are disable virtualization for Valorant's Vangaurd
- Network usage is 0% in task manager

I'm at a complete loss. I've been a Software Engineer for 15 years, but my network experience is limited.

Any suggestions for what else I can do the diagnose this would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'd have a look at https://www.bufferbloat.net/projects/ for starters - see if you can eliminate it being your network hardware/configuration. [A mid-2k Pentium is fast enough to get full throughput on a 1gbps connection [I have one here I use as my gateway to the whole building], so we ought to be fairly safe in assuming it's not intrinsic to your hardware, it's a configuration …somewhere]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @Tetsujin. 

I got this result for my phone: https://www.waveform.com/tools/bufferbloat?test-id=1cfd88e7-93a4-49f5-8f18-a6480e8c6833

My PC is stuck on "Warming Up" for the download step. Waited for about 30 minutes with no luck. It won't even finish the test

Comment: Presumably the phone is on WiFI - try the desktop both wired & Wifi & see how it compares. [phone results are absolute pants, btw… but I guess you knew that already ;))

Comment: Wow, PC passed with flying colors on WiFi: https://www.waveform.com/tools/bufferbloat?test-id=dbc99de7-a4ce-454f-b66b-7f7b1f8234ec

I just realized that my WiFi adapter was plugged into a 4-way splitter, which definitely could have been why it was so slow before.

I guess that means it's either:
1. My motherboard / network hardware
2. The LAN ports on the router?

Would really like to get this fixed for ethernet. Either way, thanks for at least getting me this far!

Comment: I can't be specific, but bufferbloat has some useful workthroughs to help, as does DSLReports.com It's really worth trying anything they suggest & see what combo works. You're still a long way short of what you're paying for. This is my result on a 200/20 line. I'm getting pretty much what I'm paying for [& this is peak time locally so contention ratios are high] https://www.waveform.com/tools/bufferbloat?test-id=2f8a329e-f483-4f91-adf3-f7af96ad7f42

Comment: Thank you so much. You have no idea how much this has been bothering me. This was incredibly helpful. I'll take all this info and investigate further.

Comment: Wired connections should be at least as fast as Wi-Fi - anything else indicates a problem with the wired connection. You could try using a different port on the router or replacing the cable with a different one. I don't like "just use wi-fi" as a solution, because wi-fi sucks, relatively speaking.

Comment: Yep I agree... unfortunately I've tried every port and multiple cords